# Need phpunit test cases for login , logout redirect (not in laravel)

Tags: phpunit

I need phpunit test cases for login, redirect and logout.

Can you please share it.

Thanks

Comment: You need to write those tests yourself.

Comment: what is phpunit function use for redirect ?